# Why curly braces ({ }) don't work in a SUMIFS in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to do this in Excel 2010:

```
=SUMIFS(Main!I:I,Main!J:J,"A",Main!K:K,{"OptionA","OptionB"})
```

I want to sum up all Main!I:I
where this is true:

- `Main!J:J` is "A"
- `Main!K:K` is either "OptionA" or "OptionB"

I've seen the curly braces in other sites, they are supposed to be like an OR, but it isn't working, I just get the OptionA ones.

This is to avoid doing a `SUM` of multiple `SUMIFS`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try containing your formula within an =sum() formula, like this....

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(Main!I:I,Main!J:J,"A",Main!K:K,{"OptionA","OptionB"}))
```

Then, it will take more than just the first criteria within your curly brackets into account.

Comment: This is very useful, however in mu case, I need to subtract the 2 criteria. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Some worksheet functions just aren't designed to take array parameters and some are. Those that aren't take the first element of the array as the sole argument. I prefer to use SUMPRODUCT when I have complicated AND and OR situations.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((J4:J14="A")*((K4:K14="OptionA")+(K4:K14="OptionB"))*(I4:I14))
```

Think of the asterisk as AND and the plus as OR. I'm pretty liberal with the parentheses, but it helps keep it clear (to me). For each comparison, a TRUE or FALSE is returned. Then the resulting arrays are multiplied or added together. TRUEs are like 1 and FALSEs are like 0.